# npm redis psubscribe issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, socket.io

I subscribed redis with channel name `order` and I want to send a push notification to all the connected clients(`let say, 5 clients connected`) and the problem is that each client gets 5 push notification instead of 1.

```
io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {    
    console.log('Connected :)');

    redis.on("pmessage", function (pattern, channel, message) {
        var data = JSON.parse(message);
        socket.emit(channel, message);

        // request for push notification
        request({}, function (error, response, res_body) {});
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('Cashier Disconnected :(');
    });
});
```

Any helpful suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Does `pmessage` subscriber receives 5 requests? or the push notification is pushing 5 times?

Comment: @SrikanthJeeva no it only receives 1 requests.

Comment: what is the code that is used to push notification? ` request({}, function (error, response, res_body) {});` will this push notification?  Could you update the code where you push notifications publishes? also the client side code that subscribes the notification.